# check if argv contains a specific file extension

Tags: c, string, argv

Im working on a program in C that takes arguments as input. Is it possible to check if your argv contains a specific file extension? Like check if any char* in argv ends in .jpeg or something like that? (any example code would be greatly appreciated :) )

Comment: Show us what you've tried and maybe we can help. A good starting point might be `strrchr()` looking for `'.'` to find the beginning of a possible extension.

Comment: I realy did not know where to start, i tried setting some delimiters and such to split the input on a '.' , but that didnt work out, so i ran out of ideas and i couldnt find any sensible way on google.
Thanks a lot to @Olaf Dietsche for a great and clear solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look for the last `.` with [`strrchr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr) and then compare for the extension with [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

```
int found = 0;
char *p = strrchr(argv[1], '.');
if (p)
    found = strcmp(p, ".jpeg") == 0;
```

---

Alternatively, take the length of the extension off the end of the string and compare that

```
const char *ext = ".jpeg";
size_t xlen = strlen(ext);
size_t slen = strlen(argv[1]);
int found = strcmp(argv[1] + slen - xlen, ext) == 0;
```

This will also work in cases like `.tar.gz`.

Comment: this works only for cases where the delimiter is not contained in the substring. E.g. it does not work to detect `".tar.gz"`

Answer (score 1):

```
bool ends_with(char const *str, char const *suffix)
{
    size_t l0 = strlen(str);
    size_t l1 = strlen(suffix);

    if (l0 < l1)
        return false;

    return strcmp(str + l0 - l1, suffix) == 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (ends_with(argv[i], ".jpeg"))
            do_something();
    }
}
```